# Gitlab Permission denied (publickey

Tags: ssh, gitlab, permission-denied

Soo i've seen many tickets about this error but none matches exactly to mine. Im trying to push changes to repo that's been created lately and im keep getting this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Funny thing i can easly push changes to other repo that's been up for months. I have an ssh added and permission to do that in gitlab. So im not sure whats seems to be the problem. Do i need to add new ssh key to my gitlab acc?

Answer (score 3):

Check first the remote URL of the problematic repository, compared to the remote URL used for other repositories where the push succeeds.

```
cd /path/to/repo
git remote -v
```

If those other URLS are HTTPS (`https://gitlab.com/<user>/<repo>`) instead of SSH (`git@gitlab.com:<user>/<repo>`), they would not use the SSH key anyway.

Check also that `ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com` does succeed.

Comment: Both repo's are SSH, after running 'ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com' im getting 'Permission denied(public key)'

Comment: As long as `ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com` fails, those repositories won't be accessible through an SSH URL. I would need to the the output of that test command to see what is going on. Check that `~/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)` are there.